# struggling with "did you forget to signal async completion?"

Tags: gulp, azure-devops, obfuscation

I know  this can be duplicate question, but i have almost spend 1 day to make it working.

so, i have gulpfile.js like here

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const javascriptObfuscator = require('gulp-javascript-obfuscator');
gulp.task("javascriptObfuscator", (done) => {
    gulp.src('./js/**/*.js', {base: './'})
        .pipe(javascriptObfuscator())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        done();
 });
```

so when i'm running this file in azure pipeline under "Gulp task", facing this error "did you forget to signal async completion?"

Answer (score 0):

try to add return before gulp.src as following:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const javascriptObfuscator = require('gulp-javascript-obfuscator');
gulp.task("javascriptObfuscator", (done) => {
    return gulp.src('./js/**/*.js', {base: './'})
        .pipe(javascriptObfuscator())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        done();
 });
```

will help if you watch: 
title:How to Upgrade to Gulp 4 
link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HpNiyimo8E